# CLion showing error using boost

Tags: c++, boost, clion

So I was starting my first project using CLion and the boost library, and following the "getting started" guide from the boost webpage, I have written the following program:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    using namespace std;
    std::for_each(
        istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), istream_iterator<int>(), cout <<(_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

Now I have `cout <<(_1 * 3) << " "`underlined as an error in the IDE saying that the binary operator `<<` is not being applied to the correct types. However the program compiles and runs without errors.

It is not a major issue, but it's a bit annoying and I'm quite curious about the cause of it.

Comment: boost::lambda makes heavy use of templates and meta-programming, plus a bit of macros. CLion built-in parser has a hard time figuring them out; it thus does not "understand" that `(_1 * 3)` is an integer (as the result of a lambda: `int -> int`).